# Django Rest Framework - How to test ViewSet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble testing a ViewSet:

```
class ViewSetTest(TestCase):
    def test_view_set(self):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        view = CatViewSet.as_view()
        cat = Cat(name="bob")
        cat.save()

        request = factory.get(reverse('cat-detail', args=(cat.pk,)))
        response = view(request)
```

I'm trying to replicate the syntax here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing#forcing-authentication

But I think their AccountDetail view is different from my ViewSet, so I'm getting this error from the last line:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attributes 'items'
```

Is there a correct syntax here or am I mixing up concepts? My APIClient tests work, but I'm using the factory here because I would eventually like to add "request.user = some_user". Thanks in advance!

Oh and the client test works fine:

```
def test_client_view(self):
    response = APIClient().get(reverse('cat-detail', args=(cat.pk,)))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: I was trying to get force auth to work, as per their docs but it doesn't seem to work. I don't use drf native auth tokens but my own jwt tokens so can't get it going via APIRequestFactory.

Answer (score 33):

I think I found the correct syntax, but not sure if it is conventional (still new to Django):

```
def test_view_set(self):
    request = APIRequestFactory().get("")
    cat_detail = CatViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})
    cat = Cat.objects.create(name="bob")
    response = cat_detail(request, pk=cat.pk)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

So now this passes and I can assign request.user, which allows me to customize the retrieve method under CatViewSet to consider the user.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue, and was able to find a solution.

Looking at the source code, it looks like the view expects there to be an argument 'actions' that has a method items ( so, a dict ).

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L69

This is where the error you're getting is coming from.  You'll have to specify the argument actions with a dict containing the allowed actions for that viewset, and then you'll be able to test the viewset properly.

The general mapping goes:

```
{
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
}
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers

In your case you'll want {'get': 'retrieve'}
Like so:

```
class ViewSetTest(TestCase):
    def test_view_set(self):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        view = CatViewSet.as_view(actions={'get': 'retrieve'}) # <-- Changed line
        cat = Cat(name="bob")
        cat.save()

        request = factory.get(reverse('cat-detail', args=(cat.pk,)))
        response = view(request)
```

EDIT: You'll actually need to specify the required actions.  Changed code and comments to reflect this.

Answer (score 10):

I found a way to do this without needing to manually create the right viewset and give it an action mapping:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, resolve
...
url = reverse('cat-list')
req = factory.get(url)
view = resolve(url).func
response = view(req)
response.render()
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's your last line. You need to call the CatViewSet as_view(). I would go with:

```
response = view(request)
```

given that you already defined `view = CatViewSet.as_view()`

EDIT:

Can you show your `views.py`? Specifically, what kind of `ViewSet` did you use? I'm digging through the DRF code and it looks like you may not have any actions mapped to your ViewSet, which is triggering the error.

Comment: last line, I'm able to go to the debugger before it, everything is defined but I think maybe there's something special about passing request into ViewSet?

Comment: Try passing the `pk` in last line. Check out the Rendering Responses example on that same page. Third line: `response = view(request, pk='4')`

Comment: hmm I've tried passing it in, same error for `view(request, pk=cat.pk)` and `view(request, cat.pk)`

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py` and `views.py` file? Also, you could try changing your second-to-last line to use a hard-coded path to make sure it works before using reverse.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get this working with force authentication, and finally got it, here is what my test case looks like:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from rest_framework.test import force_authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from config_app.models import Config
from config_app.apps import ConfigAppConfig
from config_app.views import ConfigViewSet

class ViewsTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create a test instance
        self.config = Config.objects.create(
            ads='{"frequency": 1, "site_id": 1, "network_id": 1}',
            keys={}, methods={}, sections=[], web_app='{"image": 1, "label": 1, "url": 1}',
            subscriptions=[], name='test name', build='test build', version='1.0test', device='desktop',
            platform='android', client_id=None)

        # Create auth user for views using api request factory
        self.username = 'config_tester'
        self.password = 'goldenstandard'
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(self.username, 'test@example.com', self.password)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        """setup_class() before any methods in this class"""
        pass

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        """teardown_class() after any methods in this class"""
        pass

    def shortDescription(self):
        return None


    def test_view_set1(self):
        """
        No auth example
        """
        api_request = APIRequestFactory().get("")
        detail_view = ConfigViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})
        response = detail_view(api_request, pk=self.config.pk)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 401)

    def test_view_set2(self):
        """
        Auth using force_authenticate
        """
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.username)
        detail_view = ConfigViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})

        # Make an authenticated request to the view...
        api_request = factory.get('')
        force_authenticate(api_request, user=user)
        response = detail_view(api_request, pk=self.config.pk)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I'm using this with the django-nose test runner and it seems to be working well. Hope it helps those that have auth enabled on their viewsets.

Answer (score 0):

I created a package just for that:

[drf-api-action](https://github.com/Ori-Roza/drf-api-action)

drf-api-action elevates DRF testing with the api-action decorator, simplifying REST endpoint testing to a seamless, function-like experience.

```
from drf_api_action.decorators import action_api
from drf_api_action.mixins import APIRestMixin
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class DummyView(APIRestMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DummyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DummySerializer

    @action_api(detail=True, methods=["get"], serializer_class=DummySerializer)
    def dummy(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=self.get_object())
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


def test_dummy():
    api = DummyView()
    result = api.dummy(pk=1)
    assert result['dummy_int'] == 1
```