# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-detail' with no arguments not found

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a fairly simple retrieve test:

```
def test_user_retrieve(self):
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    User.objects.create_superuser(username='test', password='Welcome2', email='test@test.com')
    user = User.objects.get(username='test')
    view = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})
    url = reverse('core:user-detail')
    request = factory.get(url)
    force_authenticate(request, user=user)
    response = view(request, pk=1)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

It gives the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\enterpass\api\core\tests.py", line 54, in test_user_retrieve
    url = reverse('core:user-detail')
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 632, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-detail' with no arguments not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/v1/core/users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/v1/core/users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$']
```

If I hit the URL using postman there's no issue:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/core/users/1/
```

The view is being registered via a router like so:

```
app_name = 'core'
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet, base_name='user')
```

here is the part of the view that's pertinent:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes_by_action = {'list': [CanListUser],
                                    'create': [CanCreateUser],
                                    'retrieve': [CanRetrieveUser],
                                    'update': [CanUpdateUser],
                                    'destroy': [CanDestroyUser]}

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance = self.get_object()
            self.check_object_permissions(self.request, instance)
            serializer = UserSerializer(instance, context={'request': request})
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Found the solution but I'd love someone to explain for me based on this working view:

```
def test_user_retrieve(self):
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    User.objects.create_superuser(username='test', password='Welcome2', email='test@test.com')
    user = User.objects.get(username='test')
    view = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})
    url = reverse('core:user-detail', args=(User.pk,))
    request = factory.get(url)
    force_authenticate(request, user=user)
    response = view(request, pk=1)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

For some reason I have to specify the positional argument in the URL and then in the response I need to specify the id.  Solution was pulled from here:

[Django Rest Framework - How to test ViewSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072730/django-rest-framework-how-to-test-viewset#23091705)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you forgot to pass required parameters with `reverse`. Add the pk of user with reverse like below.

```
userPK = 123  # User ID
url = reverse('core:user-detail', args=[userPK])
```